# Alternative malt extract for Northwestern Gold LME

Tags: dme, lme

I was thinking of making [this](http://beerrecipes.org/showrecipe.php?recipeid=553) recipe but my homebrew store doesn't have any Northwestern Gold LME.

Would any old light malt extract be an okay replacement? A full list of (liquid) malt extracts I can buy is [here](https://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/ingredientsadditivessteriliser-liquid-malt-extract-c-3_38.html).

Cheers

Comment: The problem with using anything other than light extract is that you have no idea what they use in it.  Gold extract could have crystal malt, Munich...who knows?  A quick web search doesn't turn up a list of ingredients.  Maybe of you contact them directly they can give you some info.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Northwestern's website (http://www.northwesternextract.com/brewing/malt/), their Gold LME is equivalent to light LME (not extra light) from other companies. It falls right in between their Extra Light and Amber LMEs.

Based on this Home Brew Talk thread (http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f12/what-gold-lme-126714/), the last post explains that Briess also has a Gold LME and what's used to make it. I would guess that's very similar to Northwestern's.